# How to get the HDFS server metadata information in a java client?

Tags: java, hadoop, connection, client, hdfs

I need to build a utility class to test the connection to HDFS. The test should display the sever side version of HDFS and any other metadata. Although, there are lot of client demos available but nothing on extracting the server metadata. Could anybody help?

Please note that my client is a remote java client and dont have the hadoop and HDFS config files to initialise the configuration. I need to do it by connecting to the HDFS name node service using its URL on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop exposes some information over HTTP you can use. See [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/)'s article.
Probably the easiest way would be to connect to the `NN` UI and parse the content
returned by the server:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
...
```

On the other hand if you know the address of the NN and JT you can connect to them
with a simple client like this (Hadoop 0.20.0-r1056497):

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DatanodeInfo;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.FSConstants.DatanodeReportType;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClusterStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo;

public class NNConnTest {

    private enum NNStats {

        STATS_CAPACITY_IDX(0, 
                "Total storage capacity of the system, in bytes: ");
        //... see org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol 

        private int id;
        private String desc;

        private NNStats(int id, String desc) {
            this.id = id;
            this.desc = desc;
        }

        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

    }

    private enum ClusterStats {

        //see org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClusterStatus API docs
        USED_MEM {
            @Override
            public String getDesc() {
                String desc = "Total heap memory used by the JobTracker: ";
                return desc + clusterStatus.getUsedMemory();
            }
        };

        private static ClusterStatus clusterStatus;
        public static void setClusterStatus(ClusterStatus stat) {
            clusterStatus = stat;
        }

        public abstract String getDesc();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InetSocketAddress namenodeAddr = new InetSocketAddress("myhost",8020);
        InetSocketAddress jobtrackerAddr = new InetSocketAddress("myhost",8021);

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        //query NameNode
        DFSClient client = new DFSClient(namenodeAddr, conf);
        ClientProtocol namenode = client.namenode;
        long[] stats = namenode.getStats();

        System.out.println("NameNode info: ");
        for (NNStats sf : NNStats.values()) {
            System.out.println(sf.getDesc() + stats[sf.getId()]);
        }

        //query JobTracker
        JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(jobtrackerAddr, conf); 
        ClusterStatus clusterStatus = jobClient.getClusterStatus(true);

        System.out.println("\nJobTracker info: ");
        System.out.println("State: " + 
                clusterStatus.getJobTrackerState().toString());

        ClusterStats.setClusterStatus(clusterStatus);
        for (ClusterStats cs : ClusterStats.values()) {
            System.out.println(cs.getDesc());
        }

        System.out.println("\nHadoop build version: " 
                + VersionInfo.getBuildVersion());

        //query Datanodes
        System.out.println("\nDataNode info: ");
        DatanodeInfo[] datanodeReport = namenode.getDatanodeReport(
                DatanodeReportType.ALL);
        for (DatanodeInfo di : datanodeReport) {
            System.out.println("Host: " + di.getHostName());
            System.out.println(di.getDatanodeReport());
        }

    }

}
```

Make sure that your client should use the `same` Hadoop version as your cluster does otherwise `EOFException` can occur.

Answer (score 0):

All hadoop nodes exposes the JMX interface and one of the features you can get via the JMX is the version. Good way to start is to run the Hadoop on your localhost and jconsole and connect to some node and explore the interface and copy&past the object names of MBeans. Unfortunately, there is nearly no documentation about Hadoop's JMX iface.

btw. `NameNode` provides the most useful information.

Comment: Thats a good option. But, to do that I would need HDFS to be explicitly JMX enabled and have its port number from the user; which is a bit too much to ask for such unnecessary information. My requirement is to test a HDFS connection to check if its valid  just the way you would check a JDBC connection to a Database server. The test function would say if the connection was successful or not with some additional metadata information like the server side version information.

Comment: The JMX is enabled by default, but I admint, it may be an overkill for your usecase. You may also try http://<hostname>:50070/dfshealth.jsp (should be enabled by default as well)