# submitJob method in JobClient of Hadoop throws null pointer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am tryng to execute a MapReduce job and I want to periodically poll its status. I am trying to use the submitJob(jobConf) method of Jobclient class in the code as follows

```
 JobConf conf = new JobConf(SampleJobClass.class)   
 JobClient j= new JobClient();
 j.setConf(conf);
 System.out.println("from conf" +j.getConf().toString());
 RunningJob submitJob=j.submitJob(conf);`
```

I keep getting a null pointer error at the line `j.submitJob(conf)`
The error stack is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:818)
```

Any ideas as to what I m getting wrong ?

Comment: What Hadoop version are you using?

Comment: hadoop-2.0 and CDH4 jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided information I assume you use hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0 / 4.0.1.
At line 844:

```
return ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<RunningJob>() {
```

the NPE might occur because ugi is null. (*UserGroupInformation*) This is set in the
`init()` method but this is not called in the default constructor.
Therefore, call it either manually:

```
j.init(conf);
```

or use simply:

```
j = new JobClient(conf);
```

which calls *init()* internally.

On the other hand I'd rather run the Hadoop job in command line and then execute some client code which polls the job information, E.g:

```
InetSocketAddress jobtrackerAddr = new InetSocketAddress("myhost",8021);
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(jobtrackerAddr, conf);
JobStatus[] runningJobs = jobClient.jobsToComplete();
...
```

(For retrieving several cluster information see my earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12388997))

Comment: Adding j.init(conf) works .. Gets me the output though it still hits on a null pointer and gives the following stack trace

Comment: Bending : Please check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796625/how-to-set-outputcommitter-config

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well.
But using `j.runJob(conf);` works well.
Also you can use the static function `JobClient.runJob(conf);`
I do not know why,but I go to read the source of JobClienta and find the implement of static function runJob.

```
public static RunningJob runJob(JobConf job) throws IOException {
JobClient jc = new JobClient(job);
RunningJob rj = jc.submitJob(job);
try {
  if (!jc.monitorAndPrintJob(job, rj)) {
    throw new IOException("Job failed!");
  }
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
return rj;
```

}
So I use the submitJob funciton in this way:

```
JobClient jcli = new JobClient(jconf);
        RunningJob rJob = jcli.submitJob(jconf);
        while (true){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(rJob);
            if (rJob.isComplete())
                break;
        }
```

I works!!Maybe this is also useful to you.