# How to set OutputCommitter config?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a mapreduce code that submits job using JobClient . I keep getting this null pointer error stack

```
12/12/10 12:42:44 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$NetworkedJob.<init>(JobClient.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:924)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:844)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:818)
        at FTPIF.run(FTPIF.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at FTPIF.main(FTPIF.java:273)
```

The piece of code that gets me this error is

```
JobClient j = new JobClient();
        j.init(conf);
        RunningJob check = j.submitJob(conf);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Didn't you forget adding `j.setConf(conf)` after instantiating `JobClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out why I hit on the null pointer . Setting j.setConf(conf) also did not work . So I used `runJob` instead to get a handle on the running job .

```
RunningJob job= JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem as well.
But using `j.runJob(conf);` works well.
Also you can use the static function `JobClient.runJob(conf);`.
I do not know why, then I read the source of JobClient and find the implementation of the static function `runJob`:

```
public static RunningJob runJob(JobConf job) throws IOException {
    JobClient jc = new JobClient(job);
    RunningJob rj = jc.submitJob(job);
    try {
        if (!jc.monitorAndPrintJob(job, rj)) {
            throw new IOException("Job failed!");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return rj;
}
```

So I use the `submitJob` function in this way:

```
JobClient jcli = new JobClient(jconf);
RunningJob rJob = jcli.submitJob(jconf);
while (true){
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println(rJob);
    if (rJob.isComplete())
        break;
}
```

I works!! Maybe this is also useful to you.