# How to get jobtracker details in hadoop1.2 cluster using hadoop api in java client.

Tags: java, hadoop

Issue: I am getting some cluster Details using hadoop api of namenode and datanode. Now i want to get IPAdd and port no. of jobtacker. But its not working using jobclient or jobtacker class.

```
Flow is like this: 
1) user will enter namenode hostname and port 
2) using hadoop api i am getting info about datanode and few other info of namenode.
```

Now how i can get information of jobtracker as it can be on namenode or it can be on some other machine with out giving any inputs from myside.

Pls refer link to get how i am getting cluster details using hadoop api  [How to get the HDFS server metadata information in a java client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366482/how-to-get-the-hdfs-server-metadata-information-in-a-java-client)